# Getting Class not Found Exception error in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

[My project structure as shown in image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdDD7.png)

Authority.java

```
package com.easkart.domain.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5888173406859788817L;
private final String authority;

public Authority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

}
```

Role.java

```
package com.easkart.domain.security;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
private int roleId;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
    return userRoles;
}

public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}

}
```

UserRole.java

```
package com.easkart.domain.security;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.easkart.domain.User;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long userRoleId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;

public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

public long getUserRoleId() {
    return userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(long userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

}
```

User.java

```
package com.easkart.domain;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.easkart.domain.security.Authority;
import com.easkart.domain.security.UserRole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
/**
 * 
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long userId;
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String phone;
private boolean enabled = true;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
    return userRoles;
}

public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuhority = new HashSet<>();
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        grantedAuhority.add(new Authority(userRole.getRole().getName()));
    }
    return grantedAuhority;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return enabled;
}

}
```

When I run this code as Spring boot app; I get below exception

> 2018-11-05 22:21:35.643 ERROR 5136 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.easkart.domain.User]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at com.easkart.EaskartApplication.main(EaskartApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.easkart.domain.User]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>           ... 16 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.easkart.domain.User
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>           ... 28 common frames omitted

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Move your Main, to the root package. So that your structure looks like something like the following.

```
src/main/java
    -> EaskantApplication (which I guess is the Main class)
        -> All other packages
```

Normally, when the Main class is not located at the root, it tends to fail finding the need resources.

Comment: Thanks Alain for your reply.Now I am getting below warning ** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.

Comment: When I remove security package and references of classes belonging to security package from User class , it works

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad you could fix your problem!

Answer (score -1):

Move EaskartApplication.java to a new package
e.g. com.easkart.app

Comment: Thanks kossak, it works now. I Really appreciate your help.